# Visual Studio 2010: Custom Build Rules for matching filenames

Tags: visual-studio-2010, custom-build-step, custom-build

I have a custom build rule (.props, .targets, .xml files) in my VS2010 project that compiles all files with a certain file extension with a 3rd party tool.

However, I would like it to only be applied to files with certain filenames. The problem is that the new VS2010 custom build rule system is still too complicated for me and I have no idea where I would put the condition.

As it is the rule was converted from a VS2008 .rules file. I have a feeling that this is also more complicated than it needs to be for such a simple command line build rule.

Could anyone perhaps show me a minimal example of the .targets etc. files that's needed to have a command line build rule applied to all files matching a certain filename pattern eg. (Image_*.jpg)?

Thanks in advance.